# show dialog during uninstallation using UIRef wixUI_InstallDir

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.6

I have added dialog in wix library and calling it in installuisequence as

```
<Show dialog="mycheck" after="cutomaction">REMOVE="ALL"</Show>
```

It is not showing while uninstallation. While uninstallation UI is minimal (show only progress bar).

How can we add new dialog while uninstallation?

Comment: As far as I am aware if you uninstall from Add/Remove programs then it shows only the progress bar unless you create a custom action to call your dialog set. But if the MSI is clicked twice then the Maintenance dialog's come up and your custom dialog should be displayed there.

Comment: I did not find way to call dialog from custon action instead tried with "SHOW DIALOG" with condition REMOVE="ALL" . 

this condition is also not allowed in installexecutesequence. need to call only from "installUIsequence". 

always it is not getting called with condition remove="all".


IS there any other way?

Comment: I think it has to be called from a custom action from a DLL..:)